# Use single ajax function for all events with custom data params

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, parameters

I don't know if the question itself is correct, but here is explanation.

For example, i have function `load_window()` and tons of click, change (etc) events.

How to correctly create `custom_data` variable in events and use it in `load_window()` function? Basicly, after successful event, i want to store that variable in function and load ajax with that custom data variable.

Am i close to this one, or i need to rewrite whole thing?

```
 function load_window() {
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url+'/window',
     dataType: "html",
     data: {custom_data},
     success: function(data) {
      $('#window').html(data);
      return data;
     }
   });
}

$('body').on('click', '#div', function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   var this_id = $(this).data('id');
   var custom_data = "'id':"+this_id;
   load_window();
});

$('body').on('change', '#div > .div > select', function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   var custom_id = $(this).data('id');
   var custom_data = "'id':"+custom_id;
   load_window();
});

// etc
```

Sorry for bad english and thanks for any answers.

Comment: you could pass your custom_data variable as load_window()'s param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve the issue in two ways. Firstly you could pass the data to your `load_window()` function.

Note that the manner you're currently using to create the object is not syntactically correct, and will give a different result to what you're expecting. You need to provide the key and value separately, not as a single string provided to the object. Also note that you cannot `return` anything from an asynchronous handler. If you need to use the returned `data`, do it in the callback. Try this:

```
function load_window(requestData) {
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url + '/window',
     dataType: "html",
     data: requestData,
     success: function(data) {
       $('#window').html(data);
       // do something with data here, don't 'return' it.
     }
   });
}

$('body').on('click', '#div', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   load_window({ id: $(this).data('id') });
});

$('body').on('change', '#div > .div > select', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   load_window({ id: $(this).data('id') });
});
```

Alternatively you can provide the `load_window()` function *reference* to the event handlers and get the `data('id')` using the `this` reference within the function:

```
function load_window() {
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url + '/window',
     dataType: "html",
     data: { id: $(this).data('id') },
     success: function(data) {
       $('#window').html(data);
       // do something with data here, don't 'return' it.
     }
   });
}

$('body')
  .on('click', '#div', load_window)
  .on('change', '#div > .div > select', load_window);
```

Comment: All answers is working, but your answer is more detailed and more "straight to the point" with couple of methods. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

It's just my opinion but i'd do something like this:

```
function load_window(id) {
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url+'/window',
     dataType: "html",
     data: {id:id},
     success: function(data) {
      $('#window').html(data);
      return data;
     }
   });
}

$('select').on('change', '#div > .div > select', function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
   var custom_id = $(this).data('id');
   load_window(custom_id);
});
```

this will sligthly reduce the number of lines of code without affecting readibility but this is just my opinion

Answer (score 1):

You're close. You probably want to pass the variables to the function.

```
function load_window(custom_id, custom_data) {
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url+'/window',
     dataType: "html",
     data: {custom_data},
     success: function(data) {
      $('#window').html(data);
      return data;
     }
   });
}
```

Then when you call it

```
load_window(custom_id, custom_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

`custom_data` should be an object, not the string representation of the contents of the object. Javascript doesn't re-parse the string when you put it inside `{}`.

```
function load_window() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url + '/window',
    dataType: "html",
    data: custom_data,
    success: function(data) {
      $('#window').html(data);
      return data;
    }
  });
}

$('body').on('click', '#div', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  var this_id = $(this).data('id');
  var custom_data = {id: this_id};
  load_window();
});
```

However, using a global variable like this is generally poor design. I suggest you make it a parameter to the `load_window()` function instead of a global variable. But it will work either way as long as you pass the object properly.